# how to add bootstrap grid in side of my main RTE in umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, grid-layout, rte

I have a Document Type which has a main content box (RTE). now I wand add a grid layout inside it and add "Partial View Macro" to this grid cells.

for example create a 1*3 grid and add a summery card inside of each cell. like this view :

[image: grid layout in RTE]

in this case I implement card as a "Partial View Macro"

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you running? In Umbraco 7+ there's a Grid Datatype for exactly this functionality.

Comment: i am using U7 but grid datatype force me to add my grid out of my main content. i must render this separated from my main content. i want to give this functionality to my customers to design page by theme self.... i think if there is a bootstrap grid plugin for tinyMCE this may help me!!!!

Comment: That's not how Bootstrap works, you can't just "bootstrap" part of a page like that :-s

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a macro that can point to a separate node that contains a Grid Layout property and similar to a template calling the `GetGridHtml()` extension method, you can call it from your macro code like this:

```
Html.GetGridHtml(gridNode, "gridLayourPropertyName");
```

Where `gridNode` is an `IPublishedContent` object that your macro can have as a parameter, and `"gridLayourPropertyName"` is the Grid Layout property of that node.

I haven't used this technique using a Macro from a RTE, but I've done something similar to build a grid within another grid layout.  This may not be the best technique to follow and I'd strongly recommend looking into replacing the RTE property with a grid layout. You can use RTE as a grid editor, so you  could migrate your existing property data and then you  will have all the flexibility to create/configure/customize grid editors using [current best practices](https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Getting-Started/Backoffice/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Grid-Layout/Grid-Layout-Best-Practices) to meet your requirements.

Comment: can you explain your solution?